# debuging error script timeout passed in phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin, timeout

good time
I'm at "phpmyadmin" while importing the database
And I get the following error:
The script timed out.
Help me please.

I tried all the solutions on this site, but my problem was not solved.
I use wamp
please direct me

Answer (score 0):

This has been asked and answered elsewhere on this site, but none of those answers have been marked as "accepted" so I can't link them here as duplicates.

The best solution is to use the command line client for your import. WAMP server should allow you to access the command line, and from there it's pretty easy to switch to the desired database and use the SOURCE command.

According to the [phpMyAdmin documentation](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/faq.html#i-cannot-upload-big-dump-files-memory-http-or-timeout-problems), there are a few ways you can work to improve phpMyAdmin's behavior with this — but I want to stress that a prepackaged kit like WAMP makes changes to configuration files and may have multiple configuration files spread out in nonstandard locations, so using the command line client is still best.

However, you can modify your PHP configuration (php.ini) to increase the values of these directives: `max_execution_time`, `upload_max_filesize`, `memory_limit`, and `post_max_size`.